# plone.app BlobField and accessing file

Tags: plone, archetypes, filefield, blobstorage

In an archetype, I use a BlobField :

```
from plone.app.blob.field import BlobField
BlobField(
    name='gpx_total',
    widget=FileWidget(
        label='Gpx_total',
        label_msgid='FranceVeloTourisme_label_gpx_total',
        i18n_domain='FranceVeloTourisme',
    ),
),
```

I upload a file in this field.

Then I want to download the file via the link `at_download/gpx_total`.

The first time I have a file name "gpw_total" and the second time I have my file with the correct name.

Do I miss something ?
I have tried to reindex the catalog, but it do nothing for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand your question.  Can you please clarify?  Maybe add some code examples.

Comment: The first time I try to download my file, I've got an empty file. I have to retry the download to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [plone.app.blob.field.FileField](http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.blob/trunk/src/plone/app/blob/field.py#L303).  BlobField is meant to be used only as a base class, not as a field itself.

I can't really know if that's the root of your problem, though, since there's so little detail.